# How to use Anaconda to create an environment on Mac M1 using python 2.7?

Tags: macos, python-2.7, anaconda, apple-m1

I am trying to create an environment on my mac m1 using Anaconda using python 2.7. So I use : `conda create -n py27 python=2.7`

But it gives error:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - python=2.7

Current channels:

  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-arm64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-arm64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

I also tried `conda create -y -n py27 python=2.7`  and `conda create -c 'https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-arm64/' -n py27 python=2.7` gives me the same error. Is it possible to set up python 2.7 virtual environment on Mac M1? Or how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Python 2 is [deprecated](https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/) since 2020, you should not use it or you should transition to Python 3. As stated in the aforementioned link, you'll likely won't get help or support on Python 2.

That being said, [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) should provide some old python versions if necessary.

Comment: Ook, . Python 2 is a history now.. I remembered the hard time switching Python 2 to Python3... Thank you !